# What is the difference between lifetime risk, lifetime morbid risk, and lifetime prevalence, and lifetime cumulative incidence?

Tags: terminology, epidemiology

Would appreciate any references to specific places where these terms are clearly defined.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These terms describe various longitudinal measures of disease severity using units of time or occurrences in both the denominator and numerator of the quantity measured. Consider herpes as an example. Someone experiencing an outbreak of herpes once in their life contributes one event to the denominator of lifetime risk, regardless of the number of recurrences, or whether total outbreak time is a day or a year.

Morbid risk refers specifically to disease or unfavorable outcomes (aside from mortality) whereas some other risk outcomes might be favorable like adoption of a child.

Lifetime prevelance is the proportion of time someone spends in a specific outcome state. Returning to the herpes example, this measure would be different for an individual experiencing a one-day outbreak (defined as visible open sores) or a one-year outbreak. This has in the numerator total person-time in morbid state and in the denominator total-person time observed.

Cumulative incidence measures repeated binary outcomes like hemorrhagic strokes or stubbed toes. Number of events is in the denominator and person-time at risk is in the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for a reference regarding the terms I use [Porta's "A Dictionary of Epidemiology"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195314506) when I need to look up epidemiological terms. I found him through one of Rothmans reference in his [Epidemiology: An Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195135547) where he uses the Porta's definition of cohorts.

I don't think any of the books cover lifetime in any detail but I looked into Porta that I like. Unfortunately I can't recommend Rothmans introductory book but I think I've seen a lot of people praise his [Modern Epidemiology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0781755646) but I haven't bought it... yet...

### The following are from Porta

#### Lifetime risk

> The risk to an individual that a given health effect will occur at any
> time after exposure without regard fro the time at which that effect
> occurs

#### Lifetime morbid risk

I couldn't find this as a definition. I would look into the different definitions and combine them but it seems like a strange measure to use when you have the lifetime incidence & prevalence. I guess as @Adam Omidpanah notes the key is that morbidity is a *unfavorable* event.

#### Lifetime prevalence

> The proportion of individuals who have had the disease or condition
> for at least part of their lives at any time during their life-course.

$Prevalence = \frac{number\ of\ cases}{population\ at\ risk}$

#### Lifetime cumulative incidence

I couldn't find a clear definition for lifetime but in the cumulative incidence you can extract this definition:

The number or proportion of a group (cohort) of people who experience the onset of a health-related event during a life-course.

$Incidence\ rate = \frac{number\ of\ new\ events}{time*population\ at\ risk}$

When you have a lifetime the time is irrelevant but you may experience issues with events that can recur and therefore you might get a nonsense number. Usually you use the first event (ex. first episode of low-back pain) as your counter in these cases but it's much better to use event/person/time.

Comment: +1 Very good answer. Two thoughts: I would indeed recommend *Modern Epidemiology* as a book, though its not a great introductory book - it's a more advanced treatment of the topic. The other distinction I would make is "Lifetime morbid risk" is not only a unfavorable event, but one that does not kill you. It is often of interest to split out morbidity from mortality for diseases that might either kill you, or have lingering, lasting complications (heart disease for example).

Answer (score 0):

Point prevalence: The proportion of individuals who manifest a disorder at a given point in time.

Period prevalence: The proportion of individuals who manifest a disorder over a specific period of time (e.g., over one year).

Lifetime prevalence: The proportion of individuals in the population who have ever manifested a disorder, who are alive on a given day.

Lifetime morbid risk: The probability of a person developing the disorder during a specified period of their life or up to a specified age (lifetime morbid risk differs from lifetime prevalence in that it attempts to include the entire lifetime of a birth cohort both past and future, and includes those deceased at the time of the survey).

Answer (score 0):

From Kessler et al, 2012:

> In studies of lifetime disorders, furthermore, some researchers report estimates of lifetime prevalence (i.e. the proportion of people who have had the disorder at sometime in their life), while others report estimates of lifetime morbid risk (LMR) (i.e. the proportion of people who will eventually develop the disorder at some time in their life whether or not they have a lifetime history at the time of assessment). While LMR is reported much less frequently than lifetime prevalence (Oakley Browneet al., 2006), it is important to appreciate that measures of LMR tell us not only about the proportion of the population that has so far experienced the disorder, but also about the additional proportion of the population that is expected (based on a projection from a survival model) to experience the disorder at some time in the future. The combined information about current and future cases is sometimes more important for policy planning purposes than information about cases that have occurred to date.

Full reference:
Kessler, R.C., Petukhova, M., Sampson, N.A., Zaslavsky, A.M. & Wittchen, H.U. Twelve-month and lifetime prevalence and lifetime morbid risk of anxiety and mood disorders in the United States. Int J Methods Psychiatr Res 21, 169-84 (2012).